# Getting different lengths for the same operation with different number values in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have 2 for-loops which populate arrays with letters from the alphabet. I have a `lowercase` array set, and an `uppercase` array set. The problem is when I initialize the arrays with the letters, the lengths are coming back different.

```
char uppercase[26];
char lowercase[26];
int indexUpper = 0;
int indexLower = 0;


// Get uppercase array:
for(int a = 65; a <= 90; a++){
    uppercase[indexUpper] = a;
    indexUpper++;
}

// Get lowercase array:
for(int b = 97; b <= 122; b++){
    lowercase[indexLower] = b;
    indexLower++;
}

printf("UPPERCASE = %lu\n", strlen(uppercase));
printf("LOWERCASE = %lu\n", strlen(lowercase));

$=> UPPERCASE = 26
$=> LOWERCASE = 27
```

I apologize if this is a no brainer. I am truly trying to learn and comprehend the C language and its rules. Thanks to all who contribute.

Comment: Code can't compile -> missing `}`

Comment: Please post the whole code so that it becomes easy for those who answer

Comment: `strlen` requires a nul-terminated array. Doesn't seem to happen here.

Comment: `strlen` requires a pointer to a string as argument. You are passing someting that does not point to a string. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry my bad i seem to count it wrongly. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen()` reads the character array as long until it finds a NUL byte (`'\0'`, numerical value zero). Your arrays don't contain any, since you haven't assigned one there.

That means that `strlen` will continue reading *past the end of the array*, which is illegal, and the resulting behaviour *is not defined*. Getting a 27 is rather mild, you could be getting arbitrary numbers, or your program could crash.

If you want to use `strlen()`, you should explicitly assign a NUL byte at the end of the string, and of course allocate space for it.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char upper[27];
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 26; i++) {
        /* This only works in a character set where the letters
           are contiguous */
        upper[i] = 'A' + i;
    }
    /* i == 26 now */
    upper[i] = '\0';
    printf("len: %u\n", (unsigned) strlen(upper));
    return 0;
}
```

(Though using `strlen` here at all seems somewhat pointless, since you already *know* the number of items in those arrays.)

Answer (score 2):

When using `strlen` the char array **must** be nul terminated - but yours isn't so you have undefined behavior.

To print the size of the arrays try:

```
printf("UPPERCASE = %zu\n", sizeof uppercase);
printf("LOWERCASE = %zu\n", sizeof lowercase);
```